# jQuery Change Null Into Zero With IF Failed

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery loop :

```
var total_value = 0;
$("select.dropdown").each(function() {

    if (($(this).val()) = null) {
        $(this).val() = 0;
    }

    alert ($(this).val());
    total_value = parseInt(total_value) + parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

some of `$(this).val()` still have `null` value because user haven't select yet. but I need to sum all value. so, I need to convert `null` into `0` in order to be calculated.

but I can't alert it because there's conditional `IF` there. what's wrong with that `IF`?

Comment: the condition should be if ($(this).val() == null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for sake of calculating the sum, then you need to change the `total_value` calculation to:

```
total_value += $(this).val() == null ? 0: parseInt($(this).val(),10);
```

**Full Snippet:**

```
var total_value = 0;
$("select.dropdown").each(function() {
   total_value += $(this).val() == null ? 0: parseInt($(this).val(),10);
});
```

Comment: hi bro, your code is very short and I like it. but I still get `NaN` as result when there's `null` value. it seems that your code can't convert `null` into zero.

Comment: i kept the comparison with null as string.you just have to change the comparison statement here `$(this).val() == null`

Comment: @RobertHanson: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if ($(this).val() == null) {
    $(this).val(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using the [assignment operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)  for equality instead of one of the the equality operators [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_()) or [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) in your if-statement.

Additionally, the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function actually expects a parameter for the value you wish to set as seen below :

```
// This will compare your value to null
if ($(this).val() == null) {
    // If it is null, it will set it to 0
    $(this).val(0);
}
```